# How to uninstall postgresql on my Mac (running Snow Leopard)

Tags: postgresql, macos, osx-snow-leopard, uninstallation

Upgraded 10.6 from 10.5 and now postgres 8.1 is whacked.  To make things worse I tried installing 8.4 which I'm pretty sure just made things ten times worse.  Anyhow, the exception I'm getting when I try to fire postgres up and just createuser is this:

> createuser: could not connect to
>   database postgres: could not connect
>   to server: No such file or directory
>     Is the server running locally and
>   accepting     connections on Unix domain
>   socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

HOW do I fully get rid of postgres on my Mac so I can do a do-over?

Thanks

Comment: How did you install Postgresql, via source or some package install method?

Comment: I don't remember how I originally installed it.  Wasn't from source. I think it was the install from here:  http://www.postgresqlformac.com/

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The problem was with the PostgreSQL account sitting on my machine.

I removed the account and proceeded with the uninstall using the instructions here:

#### Automatic Uninstall:

In the installation directory, there will be a uninstall-postgresql.app file. Executing (double clicking) that will uninstall the PostgreSQL installation.

#### Manual Uninstall:

1. Stop the server:

   ```
   sudo /sbin/SystemStarter stop postgresql-8.3
   ```
2. Remove menu shortcuts:

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /Applications/PostgreSQL 8.3
   ```
3. Remove the ini file:

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /etc/postgres-reg.ini
   ```
4. Removing Startup Items:

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/postgresql-8.3
   ```
5. Remove the data and installed files:

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /Library/PostgreSQL/8.3
   ```
6. Delete the user postgres:

   ```
   sudo dscl . delete /users/postgres
   ```

Answer (score 9):

I can add this tiny command to the answer too:

```
rm /usr/bin/psql
```

Remove executable psql alias.

Comment: This is closer to the answer than the above. Apple ships with postgres binaries preinstalled (as of Lion, 10.7). There will *not* be the uninstaller that the chosen answer mentions.

Comment: well the question clearly states that its not lion but snow-leopard (10.6), but nevermind, the chosen answer works perfectly.

Comment: explain what, the line and comment stands on its own. Its an extra line for the answer above or would you rather the entire answer was repeated?

Comment: You will also need to do get rid of all the /usr/bin/pg_* executables (like pg_dump, pg_restore, etc.)

Comment: I think better is to add postgres installation /bin path to the system $PATH instead of removing parts of system. After that you will use versions of psql pg_* same as postgresql server.

Comment: I get `rm: /usr/bin/psql: Permission denied` when I try this solution. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 2):

If you have newer Postgres and/or OSX/macOS version, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9240197/565525).

Answer (score 0):

SINCE I couldn't run/find `installbuilder.sh` using the following command...

```
me@myMac:/Library/PostgreSQL/14/uninstall-postgresql.app/Contents/MacOS$ installbuilder.sh  
-bash: installbuilder.sh: command not found
```

...I went on to try the steps below:

1. ```
   me@myMac:/Library/PostgreSQL/14/uninstall-postgresql.app/Contents/MacOS$ ls -la  
   total 3112
   drwxr-xr-x  5 root  daemon      160 Sep 23 10:48 ./
   drwxr-xr-x  5 root  daemon      160 Sep 23 09:18 ../
   -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  daemon      673 Sep 23 10:48 installbuilder.sh*
   -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  daemon  1449456 Sep 23 10:07 osx-x86_64*
   -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  daemon   135216 Jul 14 11:21 uninstall-postgresql*
   ```
2. ```
   me@myMac:/Library/PostgreSQL/14/uninstall-postgresql.app/Contents/MacOS$ ./installbuilder.sh
   Unable to initialize installer
   ```
3. ```
   me@myMac:/Library/PostgreSQL/14/uninstall-postgresql.app/Contents/MacOS$ ./uninstall-postgresql  
   Usage: ./uninstall-postgresql installerName [args ...]
   ```
4. ```
   me@myMac:/Library/PostgreSQL/14/uninstall-postgresql.app/Contents/MacOS$ ./uninstall-postgresql osx-x86_64
   ```

---

## and VOILA!!!

5. This launched the uninstall GUI
6. Choose **UNINSTALL ALL / REMOVE ENTIRE INSTALLATION**
   [image]
7. The **uninstaller** will do its thing and then prompt you with this:
   [image]
8. At this point you'll want to follow the steps provided in this [PREVIOUS StackOverflow ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037729/completely-uninstall-postgresql-9-0-4-from-mac-osx-lion/9240197#9240197) - steps 3 through 6 of @user1181328's answer.  I'll list them here for convenience:

> 3. Remove the PostgreSQL and data folders. The Wizard will notify you that these were not removed.
>    `sudo rm -rf /Library/PostgreSQL`
> 4. Remove the ini file:
>    `sudo rm /etc/postgres-reg.ini`
> 5. Remove the PostgreSQL user:
>
>    - using System Preferences -> Users & Groups.
>    - Unlock the settings panel by clicking on the padlock and entering your password.
>    - Select the PostgreSQL user and click on the minus button.
> 6. Restore your shared memory settings:
>    `sudo rm /etc/sysctl.conf`
>
> That should be all! The uninstall wizard would have removed all icons and start-up applications files so you don't have to worry about those.