# completely uninstall both postgresql mac (brew install on system)

Tags: macos, osx-lion, uninstallation, homebrew

I'm having lots of problems since I've tried to install psql over my mac.
I'm suspecting on the system psql as the cause. 
I want a fresh retry over mac clean of psql.
This post helped me getting started [Completely uninstall PostgreSQL 9.0.4 from Mac OSX Lion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037729/completely-uninstall-postgresql-9-0-4-from-mac-osx-lion) , but I could not find uninstall of on-system psql.
In addition, I might have open server, how can I verify none of those server are open?

Comment: on the command line the `pg_lsclusters` will list all servers and tell you if they are running or shutdown.

Comment: Thanks you for commenting. Unfortunately 'pg_lsclusters' results 'pg_lsclusters: command not found'..