# Full uninstall of Postgresql 9.3.5

Tags: postgresql

I installed postgresql 9.3.5 on OS X 10.9.4. I also used `psql postgres` to create database etc.

Ran in some issues where postgresql no longer works. The error is:

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

So I `brew uninstall postgres`. Tried reinstalling but keep getting same error. I looked in the /Library.... and deleted the postgresql folder. Is there a way to fully remove this thing? I'm tempted to reinstall this mac but this is not the way to learn the long way of resolving this issue.

Comment: It sounds more like you may have no configured your database/setup correctly. Are you 100% sure you configured everything correctly?

Comment: Yes. It was working great. Im just lost what happened. I just want to remove everything and start fresh.

Comment: FYI: See more recent Question on uninstalling Postgres from macOS on the sister site: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/185476/19079

Answer (score -1):

[Completely uninstall PostgreSQL 9.0.4 from Mac OSX Lion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037729/completely-uninstall-postgresql-9-0-4-from-mac-osx-lion)
This should work if you had previously used brew to install postgres:

```
brew uninstall
```

Double check `/usr/local/var/postgres` is also gone.
If installed with EnterpriseDB, use the second answer. You might also try it as it seems to be a complete manual uninstall.

**Edit:** after further review, it seems this is more of an issue with Postgres on OSX where as it defaults to the local installation rather than your installation: [PostgreSQL error 'Could not connect to server: No such file or directory'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472988/postgres-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Did that. Reinstalled postgresql. I still get same arror when I typed <code>psql postgres</code> in terminal.

Comment: Are you sure there is a "postgres" database/relation? Try just `psql`

Comment: I did created a database at the first installation. Tried psql and same error