# Trouble with postgresql local development on my mac

Tags: postgresql

I have a total nightmare with trying to get started with postgresql local development on my mac.

I 1st installed it from the official site and got confused, 
Then I installed postgres.app and it complains about `HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432?`

And now I'm trying to use brew but also complains about the port.

I can't even kill the processes:

[image]

Comment: FYI: See more recent Question on uninstalling Postgres from macOS on the sister site: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/185476/19079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening because the port used by PostgreSQL is already in use (obvious right?).

Since you used the EnterpriseDB installer see the other answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037729/completely-uninstall-postgresql-9-0-4-from-mac-osx-lion/9240197#9240197).

The EnterpriseDB installer is what you get if you follow "download" links from the main Postgres web site. The Postgres team releases only source code, so the EnterpriseDB.com company builds installers as a courtesy to the community.

---

Here are some other methods to uninstall the app had you installed it via `brew`:
[Completely uninstall PostgreSQL 9.0.4 from Mac OSX Lion?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8038311/5971390)

Comment: I'm also not sure how to go about uninstalling the 1st version

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037729/completely-uninstall-postgresql-9-0-4-from-mac-osx-lion

Comment: better yet this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037729/completely-uninstall-postgresql-9-0-4-from-mac-osx-lion/9240197#9240197

Comment: I reinstallled the pg .app and it connected! However it now gives me this: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/postgresql-error-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist`

any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Looks like it needs to run as a certain user.  Did the suggested solution in that thread work for you?  If not you may want to list out what else you have tried perhaps in a new post