# How to brew uninstall postgres on OX Sierra

Tags: postgresql, macos, homebrew, uninstallation, macos-sierra

Reading from the [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037729/completely-uninstall-postgresql-9-0-4-from-mac-osx-lion), I want to uninstall postgres completely with homebrew and have used `brew uninstall postgresql` but I get this response.

```
No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql
```

I know postgres is running because when I run `ps auxwww | grep postgres` I see `/usr/local/opt/postgresql94/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres`. What am I doing wrong? I have mac Sierra

Answer (score 24):

I installed postgres using homebrew. I uninstalled it using the following steps:

Run the following command and look for the correct name something like `postgresql94`, `postgres`, `postgresql@13`. Name may varies, you have to check accordingly. In my case it was `postgresql94`.

```
brew list
```

After finding the correct name, run the following command to uninstall postgres. You have to replace `postgresql94` with the name you found in the above mentioned command:

```
brew uninstall postgresql94
```

That should do the uninstall.

---

Shortcut command for the same is

```
brew list | grep postgres | xargs brew uninstall
```

Comment: THANKS! I did this and the uninstallation happened super quick so I did `ps auxwww | grep postgres` and still see the process running though. is that normal?

Comment: did you run it using root privileges. I think you are still able to see process because some file cannot be removed because they are currently in use.

Comment: I think I have root privileges because I'm the only one using my computer. Was I suppose to add `sudo` before the `brew uninstall postgresql`? I restarted my computer and don't see it the process anymore

Comment: Actually process file is still there but now it is not able to run because all the dependent files are deleted. So it's not running.

Comment: If you use homebrew why do you use sudo?  Sudo works outside of Homebrew. Normally it might break things. Is it ok for removing stuff on Mac with brew with sudo?

Comment: In 2021, using `sudo` causes an error. Looks like Homebrew allows us to install and uninstall as regular users now (at least for Postgres).

Comment: sudo brew uninstall postgresql@9.5
Password:
Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all
build scripts full access to your system.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Earlier I used `sudo` which is not required now.