# Postgres is uninstalled but psql --version still shows a result

Tags: postgresql, macos, uninstallation

I need to install a new Version of psql on a Macbook, after i uninstall pg, i try `psql --version` and it still says "psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.5."

Pg 9.6 was installed (not installed with Homebrew). I was able to uninstall 9.6. Still says 9.3.5 is installed. But i cannot find any files belonging to any Postgres application.

Is there any way to uninstall any postgtres application 100%?

Comment: `psql --version` shows the psql version, not the PostgreSQL version

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways Postgres is installed on a Mac.

1. Homebrew
2. EnterpriseDB
3. Postgres.app

Hence, to uninstall, you need to do that differently.

There are different links and I'll share them here.

1. Homebrew - `brew uninstall postgresql` command would do.
2. EnterpriseDB - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9240197/3413323
3. Postgres.app - https://postgresapp.com/documentation/install.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for this, but I think this question is not only about Postgres installing/uninstalling, but also about the cause of psql behavior after postgres uninstalling. I have the same question now, that is why it would be nice to find a full answer to asked question.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because `psql` depends on `postgis` service, which requires psql.
If it is via Homebrew, you can run below:

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies postgresql
```