# How can I delete the PostgreSQL user in my mac? because, there is no user in the preference

Tags: postgresql, macos

I forgot how I install postgresql before.
and now I have removed it by following this steps https://stackoverflow.com/a/9240197/12381565 .

But my postgresql user didn't gone from the taskbar,
although in my user preference is doesn't have it, so I can't remove it again in the preference. 
[image: the screenshot]

Maybe I deleted it once, but I forgot about it.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed now.

When I re-check again with pgAdmin4, I see the server with the same name of this user `PostgreSQL`.

I try to delete it, and now it's gone.

Answer (score 9):

Try this in terminal:

```
sudo /usr/bin/dscl . -delete /Users/postgres
sudo /usr/bin/dscl . -delete /Users/_postgres
```

than reboot mac.

Comment: I just try it. and the postgre user  still here. Or it's because of docker? I use postgre docker now for the database system

Comment: maybe, because there isn't docker on my pc, and it worked for me