# Brew psql asks for password to user that I haven't created

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, psql

I am trying to install postgresql on my MacBook using brew. I ran the command

```
brew install postgres
```

and when the download is finished I start the service using

```
brew services restart postgresql
```

This works fine, the problem arrises when I either want to log in to psql by running `psql`
in the command line or when I want to create a database using
`createdb`

My problem is that psql asks me for a password to my user which I haven't created. The username is the same as the one for my computer so my first thought was that the password would be the same but alas it was not.

Here is the error I get after answering the password incorrectly a couple of times

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "<MyUsername>"
```

I have switched out my actual username for `<MyUsername>` but you get the point

I have scoured the web for answers to this. Here are the things that I have tried:

- The password to my computer (several hundreds of times, just to be sure)
- The default password postgres (supposedly just `postgres`)
- The empty password
- Logging into the postgres (`psql -U postgres`) user and trying the same passwords.
- Going into the pg_hba.conf file to change the database administrative login
- Uninstalling and Reinstalling a couple of times
- Bashing my head against the wall (really mad this one didn't work)

Hopefully I'm being completely blind and the default password is something obvious

Comment: "Logging into the postgres (psql -U postgres) user and trying the same passwords."  What errors did this give you?

Comment: "Going into the pg_hba.conf file to change the database administrative login"  What specifically did you do, and what was the result?  For that matter, what did you find in pg_hba.conf to start with?

Comment: Did brew ask for a password upon installation?

Comment: What was the initial `psql` command you used to connect? Have you read [Brew install](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Homebrew)?  Add answers as update to question.

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same problem, already had pgAdmin4 installed, and when i install postgresql using brew, it was asking me for password for a db named after my mac-username.

Steps that i followed:

```
 1. MOVE pgAdmin to bin
 2. brew uninstall postgresql
 3. sudo rm -rf /Library/PostgreSQL
 4. sudo rm /etc/postgres-reg.ini
 5. install postgresql again using brew : brew install postgresql
 6. psql postgres
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the bane of my postgres cli was the pgAdmin tool which had accompanied the installation of postgres from postgresql.org. Deleting pgAdmin and following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037729/completely-uninstall-postgresql-9-0-4-from-mac-osx-lion) article to completely uninstall postgres and then reinstalling psql via `brew install postgres` solved my issue

Comment: ty brother, had the same issue, i wrote a complete answer below