# PostgreSQL on my Mac - did I install it? how do I uninstall it?

Tags: macos, postgresql, postgres.app

Sorry for this noob question, but I'm not sure what I just did regarding PostgreSQL.  I downloaded and installed `Postres.app` from http://postgresapp.com/  Then I decided that I no longer wanted it and would rather just install PostgreSQL with Homebrew.  So I dragged `Postgres.app` from my applications folder to my trash and then cleaned my trash and rebooted.  Now I'm discovering that I can run `psql` from the command line with no problem and I appear to be able to create and connect to PostgreSQL databases and so forth.  So my question is: was PostgreSQL already installed on my system (Mac 10.8.2 - Mountain Lion)?  When I installed Postgres.app, was that just a wrapper that started and stopped the database for me?  (If so, why was it a 28 MB download?)  Or did I install PostgreSQL when I installed Postgres.app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this](http://postgresapp.com/documentation#toc_21) you've done ok with the Trash. You can go through the list of folders it mentions as installation directories and remove them if still present:

- Binaries: `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin`
- Headers: `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/include`
- Libraries: `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/lib`
- Shared Libraries: `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/share`
- Data: `~/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres/var`

Also you can check your psql installation running:

```
$ which psql
```

It should come from `/usr/bin/` if it was installed properly by some source (macports, brew) and I presume the PostgresApp used its own bin folder for it.

Comment: I don't have a `/Applications/Postgres.app` folder, since I trashed it.  I do have the directory `~/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var`, though -- but I'm not sure what it's purpose is.  Can I just delete the entire `~/Library/Application Support/Postgres` directory?  (`var` is the only sub-directory).  And does this mean that PostgreSQL came pre-installed on my Mac?

Comment: okay, I deleted the `~/Library/Application Support/Postgres` directory and now when I try to run `psql` from the command line I get a "could not connect to server" message.  So I guess I got rid of PostgreSQL and can now reinstall it using Homebrew.

Comment: I don't think your Mountain Lion came with postgres installed. If you want to play safe before you re-install it from brew/macports you can follow [these steps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715055/how-to-uninstall-postgresql-on-my-mac-running-snow-leopard) they are for Snow Leopard and work the same way on Mountain Lion AFAIK