# How do I uninstall ALL instances of PostgreSQL on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, macos, postgresql, homebrew

I'm migrating my Rails App to PostgreSQL and have struggled with installing PostgreSQL locally for the past few days. I've tried [Postres.app](http://postgresapp.com), [homebrew](https://www.codefellows.org/blog/how-to-install-postgresql), [EnterpriseDB](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload) and each was unsuccessful.

I finally decided to [uninstall](http://frankieinguanez.wordpress.com/2012/02/11/complete-un-installation-of-postgresql-from-mac-os-x-lion) the `psql` that comes pre-installed with Mountain Lion but that was unsuccessful as well.

ex. I ran: `sudo /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/uninstall-postgresql.app/Contents/MacOS/installbuilder.sh` in my terminal
and received a `command not found` error.

Ideally, I would like to uninstall `psql` and reinstall PostgreSQL with `brew install postgresql`
but **How do I go about uninstalling Mac OS X's `psql`?**

**FYI:**

`psql --version` is `psql (PostgreSQL) 9.1.4`

`which psql` is `/usr/bin/psql`

and I'm running on Mac OS X 10.8.2

**EDIT**
During my [homebrew](https://www.codefellows.org/blog/how-to-install-postgresql) installation, when I attempt to load PostgreSQL with:

`launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`

per `brew info postgresql`'s instruction, I receive the error

`launchctl: Couldn't stat("/Users/<username>/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist"): No such file or directory
nothing found to load`

Comment: Do you checked the others questions about this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037729/completely-uninstall-postgresql-9-0-4-from-mac-osx-lion

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715055/how-to-uninstall-postgresql-on-my-mac-running-snow-leopard

Comment: Thanks @AdrianoTadao but I have already seen those. For [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715055/how-to-uninstall-postgresql-on-my-mac-running-snow-leopard#answer-2768100) in particular. I get no errors until I run into the command `sudo dscl . delete /users/postgres` then I receive a `delete: Invalid Path <dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14009 (eDSUnknownNodeName)`

Comment: Did you run `ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents` as instructed by `brew info postgresql`?