# HowTo: Completely Uninstall Postgresql14 from MacOs Catalina If I've used the EnterpriseDB.com GUI installer

Tags: postgresql, macos, uninstallation, postgresql-14

I've **been trying** to get this to work by following the answers in these questions:

- [How to uninstall postgresql on my Mac (running Snow Leopard)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715055/how-to-uninstall-postgresql-on-my-mac-running-snow-leopard)
- [Completely uninstall PostgreSQL 9.0.4 from Mac OSX Lion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037729/completely-uninstall-postgresql-9-0-4-from-mac-osx-lion/9240197#9240197)

---

### ...but they're not working.  So, here's what I have tried instead/in addition...

.

**me@myMac:***~*$ `cd /Library/PostgreSQL/14`

**me@myMac:***/Library/PostgreSQL/14*$ `./uninstall-postgresql.app/`

```
-bash: ./uninstall-postgresql.app/: is a directory
```

**me@myMac:***/Library/PostgreSQL/14*$ `open ./uninstall-postgresql.app/`

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Library/PostgreSQL/14/uninstall-postgresql.app.
```

**me@myMac:***/Library/PostgreSQL/14*$ `open -a ./uninstall-postgresql.app/`

```
Unable to find application named './uninstall-postgresql.app/'
```

**me@myMac:***/Library/PostgreSQL/14*$ `open -a uninstall-postgresql.app/`

```
Unable to find application named 'uninstall-postgresql.app/'
```

**me@myMac:***/Library/PostgreSQL/14*$ `sudo open uninstall-postgresql.app/`

```
Password:
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Library/PostgreSQL/14/uninstall-postgresql.app.
```

**me@myMac:***/Library/PostgreSQL/14*$ `cd /Library/PostgreSQL/14/uninstall-postgresql.app/Contents/MacOS/`

**me@myMac:***/Library/PostgreSQL/14/uninstall-postgresql.app/Contents/MacOS*$ `install`

```
install            install_name_tool  installvst
install-info       installer
```

**me@myMac:***/Library/PostgreSQL/14/uninstall-postgresql.app/Contents/MacOS*$ `installer`

```
Usage: installer [-help] [-dominfo] [-volinfo] [-pkginfo] [-allowUntrusted] [-dumplog]
                 [-verbose | -verboseR] [-vers] [-config] [-plist]
                 [-file <pathToFile>] [-lang <ISOLanguageCode>] [-listiso]
                 [-showChoicesXML] [-applyChoiceChangesXML <pathToFile>]
                 [-showChoicesAfterApplyingChangesXML <pathtoFile>]
                 -pkg <pathToPackage>
                 -target <[DomainKey|MountPoint]>
```

**me@myMac:***/Library/PostgreSQL/14/uninstall-postgresql.app/Contents/MacOS*$ `installbuilder.sh`

```
-bash: installbuilder.sh: command not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SINCE I couldn't run/find `installbuilder.sh` using the following command...

**me@myMac:***/Library/PostgreSQL/14/uninstall-postgresql.app/Contents/MacOS*$ `installbuilder.sh`

```
-bash: installbuilder.sh: command not found
```

...as the other answers in my OP suggest, I went on to try the steps below:

1. **me@myMac:***/Library/PostgreSQL/14/uninstall-postgresql.app/Contents/MacOS*$ `ls -la`

   ```
   total 3112
   drwxr-xr-x  5 root  daemon      160 Sep 23 10:48 ./
   drwxr-xr-x  5 root  daemon      160 Sep 23 09:18 ../
   -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  daemon      673 Sep 23 10:48 installbuilder.sh*
   -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  daemon  1449456 Sep 23 10:07 osx-x86_64*
   -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  daemon   135216 Jul 14 11:21 uninstall-postgresql*
   ```
2. **me@myMac:***/Library/PostgreSQL/14/uninstall-postgresql.app/Contents/MacOS*$ `./installbuilder.sh`

   ```
   Unable to initialize installer
   ```
3. **me@myMac:***/Library/PostgreSQL/14/uninstall-postgresql.app/Contents/MacOS*$ `./uninstall-postgresql`

   ```
   Usage: ./uninstall-postgresql installerName [args ...]
   ```
4. **me@myMac:***/Library/PostgreSQL/14/uninstall-postgresql.app/Contents/MacOS*$ `./uninstall-postgresql osx-x86_64`

---

## and VOILA!!!

5. This launched the uninstall GUI
6. Choose **UNINSTALL ALL / REMOVE ENTIRE INSTALLATION**
   [image]
7. The **uninstaller** will do its thing and then prompt you with this:
   [image]
8. At this point you'll want to follow the steps provided in this [PREVIOUS StackOverflow ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037729/completely-uninstall-postgresql-9-0-4-from-mac-osx-lion/9240197#9240197) - steps 3 through 6 of @user1181328's answer.  I'll list them here for convenience:

> 3. Remove the PostgreSQL and data folders. The Wizard will notify you that these were not removed.
>    `sudo rm -rf /Library/PostgreSQL`
> 4. Remove the ini file:
>    `sudo rm /etc/postgres-reg.ini`
> 5. Remove the PostgreSQL user:
>
>    - using System Preferences -> Users & Groups.
>    - Unlock the settings panel by clicking on the padlock and entering your password.
>    - Select the PostgreSQL user and click on the minus button.
> 6. Restore your shared memory settings:
>    `sudo rm /etc/sysctl.conf`
>
> That should be all! The uninstall wizard would have removed all icons and start-up applications files so you don't have to worry about those.